# Detect bright white blob on Grey/light white Background

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

I am new to OpenCV and I have this project where I need to detect brighter white color blobs on grey background. Could someone help me with some possible solution, ideally with OpenCV?

Original Image:

[image: 1]

Blobs to be detected:

[image: 2]

Comment: What have you tried so far? [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do you distinguish those blobs from JPG artifacts?